# How to calculate COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX on Custom object using trigger?

Tags: trigger, custom-object, lookup, roll-up-summary

I have 2 custom objects **Parent__c** and **Child__c**. Which is having look-up relationship.
How to calculate **COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX** using trigger?
I have the below code which can only SUM, But I want COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX.

```
trigger UpdateAmount on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    set<id> ids=new set<id>();
    for(opportunity opp: trigger.new)
    {
        ids.add(opp.AccountId);
    }    
    list<Account> acc=[select id,Total_Amount__c from account where id in:ids];
    list<opportunity> op=[select id, amount from Opportunity where AccountId in:ids];
    for(Account a:acc)
    {
                  decimal sum=0;
       for(opportunity o:op )
       {
           sum=sum+o.amount;
       }
        a.Total_Amount__c=sum;
    }
update acc;
}
```

Comment: Use Aggregate Functions . https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm

Comment: Can you show the code that you are using for your Custom Objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate functions in SOQL, such as SUM() and MAX(), allow you to roll up and summarize your data in a query. For more information on aggregate functions [click](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm),

```
trigger UpdateAmount on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {
    set<id> ids=new set<id>();
    for(opportunity opp: trigger.new)
        ids.add(opp.AccountId);

    List<Account> accountsToUpdate=new List<Account>();
    Map<ID, Account> acc = new Map<ID, Account>([select id,Total_Amount__c from account where id:=ids]);
    AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT AccountId,SUM(Amount)amt FROM Opportunity where AccountId in:ids group by AccountId];

    for(AggregateResult Results: groupedResults){
         Id accountId =(id) Results.get('AccountId');         
         Account a=acc.get(accountId);
         a.Total_Amount__c=(integer)Results.get('amt');;
         accountsToUpdate.add(a);
    }    
  update accountsToUpdate;
}
```